# python3 shared list object among processes

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to share a large object among processes(which is a list of list of str) among processes in the process Pool. The object is read-only, so I don't want a lock on that.
I've tried multiprocessing.Value, but it seems that it only supports ctypes, but I want to share a list of list of str.

Also I've tried multiprocessing.Manager.list, but according to the document, the manager is a sync manager, I suppose it will have a lock on that, which is not what I want.

So what's the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It depends on what tradeoffs you are willing to make.**

I can see multiple ways of doing this, with advantages and disadvantages:

1. Create an anonymous [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html).  These are specifically designed to be shared between processes created with `multiprocessing` or `os.fork()`.  They have low overhead and translate almost directly into operating system primitives for shared memory.  The downside is that you just get one huge fixed-length array of bytes.  If you want additional structure on top of that (for example, a list of lists of strings), you need to manually serialize and deserialize it.  You may find the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) and [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) modules helpful for that purpose.  If you're feeling adventurous, you can also access the elements in-place through a [`memoryview` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview).
2. Don't share the list.  The child processes already inherit a copy of anything in the parent process's memory.  Since the list is read-only, this may have performance implications but will not produce incorrect results.  In theory, these performance implications ought to be mitigated by the copy-on-write design of a modern operating system's `fork()`.  In practice, that does nothing for us because Python reference-counts the strings, which writes to the memory and forces the OS to copy nearby data.  `array` doesn't refcount its contents and therefore might be less susceptible to this issue, if your individual arrays are large enough.
3. Create a temporary file with [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) and store the information there using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), or [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).  We may assume the temporary file is also visible to child processes, and the `tempfile` module will take care of cleaning it up for you when finished.  However, reading data from permanent storage is typically slower than in-memory solutions.